# iPad and Xcode help 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

hi and tnx in advance for support.

I need to create simple iPad application.

Structure is:

- screen with two big buttons / image if posible in middle / center of screen

This two buttons will separate my portfolio on two segments.

- After selecting one of buttons on first screan, page / screen will show with links / buttons to 4-5 child level screens.

I am totaly new (read noob) for mac and Xcode, so any help will be more than helpfull to me.

also if you know some easy way ather than using Xcode please suggest it to me ....

thank you very much in advance

Comment: What are you exactly asking? If you're just asking for someone who can do this for you, this is probably not the place.

If you just want this one simple app, you should probably go look for a place where you can ask someone who would make this for you.

If you want this app and you want to make more apps later, I would suggest looking for tutorials online (Apple has some good tutorials) or buying the books Learn Objective-C on the Mac and Beginning iPhone 4 development, both from Apress. This would get you started.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Perhaps you could learn [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/) to create a Web App? Additionally, you could then learn how to make a simple iPhone App that contains a WebView and your [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/) code.

Or slightly more complex you could use [iProcessing](http://www.creativeapplications.net/iphone/iprocessing-iphone-processing/).